# regular expressions for floating and non-floating point numbers followed by words

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

i'm tasked with a problem where there is a particular table column that always has the same type of data in it. For validation purposes i thought it would be easiest to verify that data based on a pattern match.

Example set of data:

```
*12 days ago
*1 minutes ago
*5.8 hours ago
*3.2 years ago
```

(ignore the *)
Here is the regex i came up with, but i feel its slightly off:

```
String f = "^(?:\\d+|\\d*\\.\\d+)\\s+(\\byears|months|days|hours|minutes\\b)\\s+    (\\bago\\b)$";
Pattern p = p.compile(f);
Matcher m; 

if (m.find(retreiveRow(5))) { ...... }
```

Any assistance would be great!
Many thanks!

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Something is missing, the range of the numeric part depends on the string that follows it. If you are validating, you need to range check too.

Comment: @Gabe my question is, is my regex right to match the potential strings in the example data?

Comment: apart from the `\\b` (which you don't need since you have the spaces) it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as java string : `"^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\\u0020(days|minutes|months|hours|years)\\u0020ago$"`

as plain regex: `^\d+(\.\d+)?\u0020(days|minuits|hours|years)\u0020ago$`

i deliberately restricted the whitespace to only space character. doesnt seem tab and all is applicable here.

Comment: You eliminated the possibility to say ".5 days ago". You also misspelled "minutes" and left out the "months" option.

Comment: no, .5 doesnt seem valid in current context. it should be `0.5 days ago`. though @bcar should be able to tell that. the example did not cover it. thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

**Your sample data:**

```
12 days ago
1 minutes ago
5.8 hours ago
3.2 years ago
```

**My regular expression:**

```
/^([\d]+(?:\.\d)?)\s(years|months|days|hours|minutes)/

  (..............)  (...............................)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^([\d]+                              # match one or more digits
(?:\.\d)?)                           # followed by an optional period and digit
\s                                   # followed by a whitespace character
(years|months|days|hours|minutes)    # followed by a unit-of-time word
```

The two pairs of parentheses below the regex show the two **capture groups** (backreferences) incorporated into the regex.

Although your question is with respect to **Java**, here's a [live demo](http://ideone.com/iWkkkQ) of this regex against your data using **Perl**. Perl code also here for reference:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my @buf;
while (<DATA>) {
    @buf = /^([\d]+(?:\.\d)?)\s(years|months|days|hours|minutes)/;
    print "[", join("][", @buf), "]\n";
}

__DATA__
12 days ago
1 minutes ago
5.8 hours ago
3.2 years ago
```

**Outputs:**

```
[12][days]
[1][minutes]
[5.8][hours]
[3.2][years]
```

Comment: won't match `.2` which the one in the question seems to go out of its way to do...

Comment: @andrew: `.2` can be handled by altering the first part of the regex as follows: `^([\d]+(?:\.\d)?|\.\d)`. The change is simply appending `|\.\d` to indicate the alternate match (a period followed by a single digit).